# Ubuntu 13.04 and bluez-5.8 configure: error: systemd system unit directory is required

Tags: 13.04, bluetooth

I am installing bluez 5.8 on Ubuntu 13.40 and while running ./configure, I am getting this error message.

```
checking systemd system unit dir... configure: error: systemd system unit directory is required
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 13):

I am using Mint 15 and ran into same problem while installing BlueZ 5.8.  Googling found your exact question. To solve it, had to add --with-systemdsystemunitdir and --with-systemduserunitdir configure options.  Since Mint and Ubuntu have much in common, you may find that it works for you too.  The complete command line is below.  You may want to leave out the --enable-experimental flag so you don't get experimental plugins.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --enable-experimental --with-systemdsystemunitdir=/lib/systemd/system --with-systemduserunitdir=/usr/lib/systemd
```

Comment: I did ./configure --disable-systemd and that seems to remove the error.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu @mrd.  Keep answering like this, and you will be very useful here.

Comment: good!! work fine

Answer (score 1):

Configure it without `systemD`. It will work like so:

```
./configure --disable-systemd
```