# Error "configure: error: GLib >= 2.28 is required" while configuring bluez stack

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

I was configuring the latest bluez stack on my machine (13.04 64-bit). I got following error while configuring it:

```
checking for GLIB... no
configure: error: GLib >= 2.28 is required
```

Can someone help here with the error, how to resolve it and configure bluez ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was able to solve that compiler error by issuing:

```
sudo apt-get install glib2.0
```

You might also like to refer to [Ubuntu 13.04 and bluez-5.8 configure: error: systemd system unit directory is required](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343663/ubuntu-13-04-and-bluez-5-8-configure-error-systemd-system-unit-directory-is-re)

Comment: Installing `libglib2.0-dev` only would add much less packages ;-)