# How to install requested libs: GLIB, libavcodec and libavformat?

Tags: sound, libraries, glibc, libav

I've got an application from InteractiveBrokers, which sometimes gives me this:
[image]

So I searched for those libs in synaptic, but in the screenshots below you can see that they all seem to be installed.

Does anybody know how I can solve this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: @PRATAP - 18.04. I also considered that this is simply an error by the creator of the software. Is that true?

Comment: When are you getting that error msg. Which app are you using?

Comment: @PRATAP - I'm using the Trader Workstation of InteractiveBrokers.com, a system to trade on various exchanges. I get the message when a trade has been done, so I suppose it tries to play a sound. This is not really a dealbreaker, but I would love to solve it.

Comment: Have you tried those codes to install and see? your installed codecs are higher than the required.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/396962/739431

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/libavcodec53/6:0.8.7-1ubuntu2

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/libavformat53/6:0.8.7-1ubuntu2

Answer (score 1):

An old thread but maybe interesting for others:
The latest version here needs libavcodec56 (strace was my friend ;) ).

One can simple build that version by using git (or an old release tarball).
Here is what i've done:

```
git clone https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git

# latest minor for of 56:
git checkout b94ec30428b9696f99b08055735689623fe63954

# (maybe also set "--prefix=/usr" here, or start TWS later with e.g. LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib")
./configure --enable-shared --disable-static
make -j
make install
```

Now start TWS (maybe set LD-path) and sound should play.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved this:

1. Install docker:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install docker-ce
   ```
2. Run `ubuntu:12.04` inside the container:

   ```
   docker run -d --rm --name oldubu ubuntu:12.04 sleep 1000000000
   ```
3. Go into the container:

   ```
   docker exec -it oldubu /bin/bash
   ```
4. Install some packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install make wget gcc pkg-config
   ```
5. Get old ffmpeg sources:

   ```
   wget  https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/archive/n2.5.3.tar.gz
   ```
6. Unpack it:

   ```
   tar -zxvf n2.5.3.tar.gz
   ```
7. Go into:

   ```
   cd FFmpeg-n2.5.3
   ```
8. Prepare sources:

   ```
   ./configure --prefix=/opt --enable-shared
   ```
9. Build:

   ```
   make -j
   ```
10. Install:

    ```
    make install
    ```
11. Create an archive from installed files:

    ```
    tar -zcvf libavcodec.tgz -C /opt/ .
    ```
12. Get the archive from the container:

    ```
    docker cp oldubu:libavcodec.tgz ./
    ```
13. Create some folder:

    ```
    mkdir /opt/customsoft/ffmpeg/
    ```
14. Unpack our archive:

    ```
    cd /opt/customsoft/ffmpeg/ && tar -zxvf ~/libavcodec.tgz # Now archive in my home directory
    ```
15. Open properties window of your TWS shortcut(Desktop icon) and insert `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` definition before actual command. For example in my case:

    ```
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/opt/customsoft/ffmpeg/lib "/home/bobzier/Jts/tws" -J-DjtsConfigDir="/home/bobzier/Jts" %U
    ```

[image]