# How to upgrade to the latest BlueZ version on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, bluetooth

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is using BlueZ ver4.98 which is not the latest version. I would like to upgrade to the latest BlueZ version. How can this be done?

Comment: Upgrade to the latest Ubuntu LTS version.

Comment: I don't think Ubuntu 14.04 is using the latest bluez which is ver5.3. http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/admin/bluez

Comment: And what is the latest version?

Comment: Latest is bluez ver5.3

Comment: Then you have to compile it yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get the latest version from [here](http://www.bluez.org/download/).

E.G.:

```
wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/bluetooth/bluez-5.30.tar.xz
```

*Extract*

```
tar xf bluez-5.30.tar.xz
```

*Build*

```
cd bluez-5.30
./configure
make
```

*Then install with*

```
sudo make install
```

or with `checkinstall` for a `.deb` package:

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
sudo checkinstall
```

Comment: I'm trying to install `5.44` on a `ubuntu-16.04.2` i get no error but the it cant find `gatttool` even after `sudo make install` what am i missing? its a live cd if that matters..

Comment: This was useful for Ubuntu 18.04 also, but I had to install dependencies for the ./configure step to work. `sudo apt install libdbus-1-dev libudev-dev libical-dev libreadline-dev`

Answer (score 5):

For successful build as per @A.B's [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/612330/52398), your system should meet following dependencies. I've Ubuntu 14.04.1 / Kernel 3.16.0

```
apt-get install libglib2.0-dev libdbus-1-dev libudev-dev libical-dev libreadline6 libreadline6-dev

./configure
make
make install
```

If you get an error while `./configure` saying *configure: error: systemd system unit directory*, try following solution by a user:mrd [[original post]](https://askubuntu.com/a/343927/52398).

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --with-systemdsystemunitdir=/lib/systemd/system --with-systemduserunitdir=/usr/lib/systemd
```

Comment: You should probably install the dependencies *before* `./configure`-ing the build.

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 I had to install packages `libreadline6` and `libreadline6-dev` in addition to given above