# Ubuntu 14.04 Bluez5 Broadcom BCM20702A0

Tags: 14.04, drivers, bluetooth, broadcom

So I recently upgraded to Bluez5 by building the package from source via these instructions: 
[How to upgrade to the latest BlueZ version on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612295/how-to-upgrade-to-the-latest-bluez-version-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts)

However now upon boot I get the following error:

```
[    2.255545] init: Failed to spawn bluetooth main process: unable to execute: No such file or directory<br>
[    2.553520] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is blocked<br>
[    3.170767] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A0-0a5c-21e6.hcd failed with error -2
```

Any ideas how to get bluetooth working again on my ThinkPad X230?

Thanks alot in advance and best regards,

J

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working on ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working-on-ubuntu)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure its just a firmware error as with bluez4 everything worked fine.

Comment: What is the result of `rfkill list all`

Comment: Here you go:

`0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no`

Comment: You may want to try Ubuntu 15.10 as I tried installing Bluez 5 like you did and it is a disaster

Comment: I would actually like to wait for the next LTS. No ideas how to get bluez5 working in 14.04?