# I can't update BlueZ on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, bluez

I can't update BlueZ to its latest version (5.40) on Ubuntu 14.04.

I run the commands provided in the readme file, but I get an error:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var
[…]
checking systemd system unit dir... configure: error: systemd system unit directory is required
```

According to [this question,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343663/ubuntu-13-04-and-bluez-5-8-configure-error-systemd-system-unit-directory-is-re) I should use the following command:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --enable-experimental --with-systemdsystemunitdir=/lib/systemd/system --with-systemduserunitdir=/usr/lib/systemd
```

And everything works.

Then I type the command:

```
make && make install
```

And everything works.

I check my BlueZ version:

```
bluetoothd -v
4.101
```

It didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting or restarting the bluetooth services?

Comment: Yes, I did; then I also reboot my computer.