# How to update bluez on ubuntu (14.04) to 5.46

Tags: updates, bluetooth, bluez

I have tried many things including steps here:

1. [I can't update BlueZ on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784825/i-cant-update-bluez-on-ubuntu-14-04)
2. [How to upgrade to the latest BlueZ version on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612295/how-to-upgrade-to-the-latest-bluez-version-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts)

But still not able to get latest version running.
I am still stuck at bluez v4.101

Please help with this.